# Need help on GROK pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Hi I am kind of new to ELK and also GROK pattern, below is the log file line for which I want to create a GROK pattern. The fields that I need are before the ‘=’ as parsed by Splunk.

```
01 Aug 2017 17:58:19,048 INFO ProfileAspect[{applicationSystemCode=appname, clientIP=10.x.x.x, clusterId=Cluster-Id-NA, containerId=Container-Id-NA, correlationId=536bacc1-1b50-3866-5c8c-8d0efa037f8f, domainName=defaultDomain, hostName=ip-x-x-x.domain.com, messageId=10.x.x.23-e2250a0e-b706-4e95-8e11-5b9bf310eabd, userId=ANONYMOUS, webAnalyticsCorrelationId=66D276FF1489DFF845056FD915664268|F90B27374FD5E26D2566CEE3AFDA3AB0}]: class com.provider.base.v1.HomeBaseApiConsumer.searchTasks execution time: 15 ms
```

I also want to capture the execution time which is displayed in the last i.e 15 ms in this example.

I came up with this GROK pattern which is obviously not working.

```
%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME},%{NUMBER:duration} %{WORD:loglevel} %{WORD:Activity} [{%{(“applicationSystemCode”= \w)}
```

As per the document for Custom patterns, mentioned is (?the 
pattern here)

My updated GROK pattern is

```
%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME},%{NUMBER:duration} %{WORD:loglevel} %{WORD:Activity} \[\{(?<applicationSystemCode>\W\w+\W\w+)
```

I tested the regex in regex101.com1 and it works but in grok Debugger it doesnt work.

Any body can help?

Answer (score 0):

The below grok pattern will capture applicationSystemCode and execution time. If required you can capture other fields also in same manner.

%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{WORD:Activity}[{applicationSystemCode=%{WORD:applicationSystemCode}%{GREEDYDATA:msg} execution time: %{GREEDYDATA:time}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, But i have to capture every field value pair separated by '=' sign.

Answer (score 0):

This is the online debugger that I use for debugging my grok patterns: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

'\' is for escaping special regex characters.

This is an example but I believe you can continue from here:

```
%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{WORD:Profile}\[\{applicationSystemCode=%{DATATYPE:NAMEYOUGIVE}
```

I hope I was clear and this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, But i have to capture every field value pair separated by '=' sign

Comment: You are welcome. You can continue filling the pattern like the following: %{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{LOGLEVEL} %{WORD}\[\{applicationSystemCode=%{WORD:SystemCode}, clientIP=%{CHOOSEDATATYPE:ClientIp}, clusterId=%{CHOOSEDATATYPE:clusterId},             Or I am not sure if this will work you can look for kv filter. It is meant for automatically parsing by configuring the filter. Here is the link for kv filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html

Comment: Thanks a lot , i did use the KV filters and it worked like a champ. :)

Comment: But the KV filter doest work with File input. It complains about the source in KV {}

Comment: Kv filter does work with file input and if you are getting an error message can you post it?

Comment: ERROR logstash.inputs.file - Unknown setting ‘source’ for file, may be the source option which i was using in the file input is wrong. I will refer to the documents again.